# Why does it take so long to run: bitcoind -reindex -txindex -debug=net -printtoconsole

Tags: bitcoind

If I run the following command from my `bitcoin` console client:

```
bitcoind -reindex -txindex -debug=net -printtoconsole
```

it take extremely long to run, does this `reindex` all the previous `bitcoin` transactions ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the detail about the options you use:

```
 -txindex: Maintain a full transaction index (default: 0)

 -reindex: Rebuild blockchain index from current blk000??.dat files

 -debug: Output extra debugging information. Implies all other -debug* options
```

It's normal that this operation takes time because *txindex* represent a uge amount of data and you force the bitcoin core to rebuild the blockchain from your local saves each time you run it (which is, from my experience, not necessary). My suggestion is to remove -reindex and try to figure out if you really need -txindex.

If you want to check on all the transactions related to your wallet, I think this option is more appropriate:

```
-rescan: Rescan the block chain for missing wallet transactions
```

note: this will also be time consuming

information from : http://we.lovebitco.in/bitcoin-qt/command-line-options/

Answer (score 1):

Tips for faster reindexing:

- Use `-printtoconsole=0` (will not output anything at all to the console)
- Increase dbcache from default 450 - for example, to 1000: `-dbcache=1000`